# Excel Сложное условие

Tags: excel

[image: Таблица]
Есть два столбца с числами A и B. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно написать формулу в столбце C, чтобы в ячейке проставлялась буква по условиям из таблицы?

Comment: 42 блока `Если`?

Comment: @pavel 5 блоков `если` и куча `ИЛИ(И())`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Попробую через 5 ЕСЛИ

Answer (score 1):

В случае если не хочешь хард кодить много `ИЛИ` :

1) Сделать группы в матрице подстановок ( 0-4 ,0-8) (нужно только для наглядности)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Добавить колонки для группы A и B на листе с данными ( через `если`) ( 0-4 ,0-8)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] и так далее

3) Использовать `ИНДЕКС` по матрице подстановок и доп колонками ( смещения)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Уже написал в одну длиннющую строчку, но этот способ кажется мне более перспективным, попытаюсь освоить.

Answer (score 0):

Для **A**

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1<3;B1>2);И(A1<1;B1>1,8;B1<=2));"A";0)
```

Для **B**

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1>=3;A1<5;B1>2);И(A1>=1;A1<5;B1>1,8;B1<=2);И(A1<2;B1>1,1;B1<=1,8));"B";0)
```

Для **C**

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1<9;A1>=5;B1>1,8);И(A1>=2;A1<5;B1>1,1;B1<=1,8);И(A1<2;B1>0,5;B1<=1,1));"C";0)
```

Для **D**

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1>=9;B1>-2);И(A1>=9;B1<=-2);И(A1>=5;A1<9;B1<=1,8;B1>-2);И(A1>=3;A1<5;B1<=1,1;B1>-2);И(A1>=2;A1<3;B1<=1,1;B1>0);И(A1<2;B1<=0,5;B1>0));"D";0)
```

Для **E**

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1>=2;A1<3;B1<=0;B1>-2);И(A1>=3;A1<9;B1<=-2));"E";0)
```

Для **F**

```
=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1<2;B1<=0;B1>-2);И(A1<3;B1<=-2));"F";0)
```

**Собираем все в одно выражение:**

`=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1<3;B1>2);И(A1<1;B1>1,8;B1<=2));"A";=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1>=3;A1<5;B1>2);И(A1>=1;A1<5;B1>1,8;B1<=2);И(A1<2;B1>1,1;B1<=1,8));"B";=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1<9;A1>=5;B1>1,8);И(A1>=2;A1<5;B1>1,1;B1<=1,8);И(A1<2;B1>0,5;B1<=1,1));"C";=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1>=9;B1>-2);И(A1>=9;B1<=-2);И(A1>=5;A1<9;B1<=1,8;B1>-2);И(A1>=3;A1<5;B1<=1,1;B1>-2);И(A1>=2;A1<3;B1<=1,1;B1>0);И(A1<2;B1<=0,5;B1>0));"D";=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1>=2;A1<3;B1<=0;B1>-2);И(A1>=3;A1<9;B1<=-2));"E";=ЕСЛИ(ИЛИ(И(A1<2;B1<=0;B1>-2);И(A1<3;B1<=-2));"F";0))))))`